# Evaluate the value of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

One example in my Calc$ 2 $ class wants to decide whether the series $ \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n 2^{n - 1}} $ converges or diverges. I know that this series converges by using the ratio test, but I currently stuck on finding the value of this series. WolframAlpha gives the [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%20%3D%201%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%202%5E%7Bn%20-%201%7D%7D) for this series to be $ ln4, $ but I don't know how to arrive at this. Can someone give me some hints/suggestions? WolframAlpha mentions Lerch transcendent but I haven't learned about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Define 
$$
f(x) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}
$$
Then you have
$$
f'(x) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}= \frac1{1-x}
$$
Therefore
$$
f(x) = -\ln(1-x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Let $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^{n}}{n}$, we find $f(\dfrac{1}{2})$, we can differentiate $f(x)$ and the sum is a geometric series.